# Branch.io No intent found for opening the app through uri Scheme 'de://'.Please add the intent with URI scheme to your Android manifest

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, branch.io

I am trying to integrate Branch,io in my flutter project via flutter_branch_sdk. I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3ihnIrtw_Q. I can generate link and it redirects and opens the app but not to specific screen of the app. However, when I run validateSdkIntegration method. it print this.

```
3. Verifying application package name ...
D/BranchSDK_Doctor(27965): Passed
D/BranchSDK_Doctor(27965): 4. Checking Android Manifest for URI based deep link config ...
D/BranchSDK_Doctor(27965): ** ERROR ** : No intent found for opening the app through uri 
  Scheme 'de://'.Please add the intent with URI scheme to your Android manifest.
D/BranchSDK_Doctor(27965): Please follow the link for more info 
  https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration#section-configure-app
```

My AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.dhaka_eats">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<queries>
    <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app makes calls -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app emails -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="io.branch.referral.BranchApp" android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
    >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Branch URI Scheme -->
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="de" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Branch App Links -->
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- example-alternate domain is required for App Links when the Journeys/Web SDK and Deepviews are used inside your website. -->
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/deeplink_test_link" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/deeplink_alternative_test_link" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/deeplink_test_link" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/deeplink_alternative_test_link" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyAejfMVUk4Bjnslt32AqxLSuJHOa-sdfsdf" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
    <!--
    Don't delete the meta-data below.
    This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
    -->
    <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <!-- Branch init -->
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="@string/branch_io_sdk_live_key" />
    <!-- Branch testing (TestMode "true" to simulate fresh installs on dev environment) -->
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test" android:value="@string/branch_io_sdk_test_key" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="branch_enable_log" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="branch_enable_facebook_ads" android:value="false" />
</application>
```

Comment: have you solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

add new scheme under domain configuration for example   `<data android:scheme="examplelink" />`

this code is based on your scheme:

```
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- example-alternate domain is required for App Links when the Journeys/Web SDK and Deepviews are used inside your website. -->
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/deeplink_test_link" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/deeplink_alternative_test_link" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/deeplink_test_link" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/deeplink_alternative_test_link" />
        <data android:scheme="ed"/>
    </intent-filter>
```